# MVC3 how to minimize the number of controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i am new to MVC3 and our project needs something like:

http://www.abc.com/product_1/product_1_subpage/...
http://www.abc.com/product_2/product_2_subpage/...

right now, i have product_1 as a controller; product_1_subpage as an action of this controller, however, think about i have over 100 different products, i cannot keep create over 100 controllers for each single product, i need to do something on this structure, any idea?

thank you very much for your help, really appreciate any input.

Comment: Maybe look at having your default controller/action accept product and productSubpage parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want to have only a single Controller called Products, for all your products, instead of having to add a new controller for every product.

With custom routes, or the default routing for that matter, you would still be able to generate individual links for individual products. Also, if you were to use your approach with a new controller for every product (which you really shouldn't!), you would have to re-compile and deploy your application every time you want to add another product - which would be a pain to maintain.

It sounds like you should have a look at the [tutorials about MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials) provided by the .Net team to get some basic understand of MVC, and how to think about it.

Comment: yes, i know it's not gonna work in reality, just to get something to show to boss and then move to reality, problem is that everyone in the office is new to MVC3, and no one can have any opinions on this new project. thank you.

Comment: @YanWang My best recommendation is to take a couple of hours to go through the tutorials and maybe look at a few videos - it will save you hours in the long run. When you've learned to use the scaffolding in visual studio etc., it will be much faster to get some basic CRUD working the proper way than doing it your way. I bet you will get some basic functionality working for your boss quickly as soon as you know the basics!

Comment: yeah, i already did those videos and tutorials, but when it comes to all kinds of requirements for SEO purpose, i need to pay more attention on the design. thank you.

Comment: That can't possibly be true. Christofer is right, you should use a single product controller, and look up the appropriate product by id. Let MVC routing do this for you. The best SEO is good content, not whether or not a specific character is in the URL. You're likely to get more penalized by breaking REST conventions than by not having the "_" character.

Comment: thank you very much, i will look into this matter with more research.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ProductsRoute", // Route name
            "products/{productName}/{subName}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Product", action = "View", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

That would make the following work:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    // http://yourweb/products/goggles/xray/Elite2000
    public ActionResult View(string productName, string subName, string id)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about changing the format of the url a little to take advantage of the routing:

```
http://www.abc.com/product/subpage/1
```

Comment: sorry, our boss needs the "-" for SEO purpose. but thank you very much.